# How to set up separate test and development database in meteor

Tags: mongodb, tdd, meteor

I've written a few tests for my meteor app. As they have setup and teardown methods that remove all documents or populate with new ones, I'd like to run them on a database dedicated to testing.

I notice the db is stored in .meteor/local/db . Ideally I'd like to have db_test and db_dev accessed form different ports.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to run two `mongod` processes e.g.

```
# Dev
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath .meteor/local/db_dev

# Testing
mongod --port 28017 --dbpath .meteor/local/db_test
```

---

[Edit] This should work. Using the leaderboard example project:

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/appname_dev" meteor run --port 3000
MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:28017/appname_test" meteor run --port 4000
```

That will use separate databases.

Comment: That would be ideal. However to start the mongo process in a meteor project I have to use the meteor command, which has a --port flag but no way to specify a different database - as far as I'm aware. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Updated my answer. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Did you get that to work with leaderboard? I just tried in my project and when I run the commands on the second line I get some errors:Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting. Can't start mongod. Check for other processes listening on port 4002 or other meteors running in the same project. I'm beginning to think the Meteor guys have a different philosophy for testing, and I'm just suffering from a Rails hangover ;) Thanks again for your contribution. It's shown me where I should be exploring.

Comment: Yeah, worked fine in the leaderboard example for me. Are you sure nothing is running on the 2nd port?