# Meteor - Run package tests with test database

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, tinytest

(This is similar to this question: [How to set up separate test and development database in meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166436/how-to-set-up-separate-test-and-development-database-in-meteor), however it's 2 years old and meteor has changed a lot since then.)

I'm trying to create my own package and I want to run unit tests. I want to ensure that my queries are correct, so I want to actually run queries against a test database instead of just stubbing the functions.

I have two questions:

- How can I tell Meteor to run against a test database instead of my real one?
- What's the best way to easily populate that test database with data?

Ideally, I'd a setup step to clear than populate the test database, so I always know exactly what data is in each.

I'm a Tinytest novice (though I've used other unit test frameworks), so code samples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example similar to what we use:

```js
var resetCollection = function(name) {
  var Collection = this[name];
  if (Collection)
    // if the collection is already defined, remove its documents
    Collection.remove({});
  else
    // define a new unmanaged collection
    this[name] = new Mongo.Collection(null);
};

reset = function() {
  var collections = ['Comments', 'Posts'];

  // reset all of the collections
  _.each(collections(function(name) {resetCollection(name);}));

  // insert some documents
  var postId = Posts.insert({title: 'example post'});
  Comments.insert({postId: postId, message: 'example comment'});
};

Tinytest.add('something', function(test) {
  reset();

  var post = Posts.findOne();
  var comment = Comments.findOne();
  return test.equal(comment.postId, post._id);
});
```

At the start of each test we call `reset` which cleans up the database and creates the necessary collections.

**How can I tell Meteor to run against a test database instead of my real one?**

When you test your packages, a separate database will be created for you. There is no need to manually specify your db path.

**What's the best way to easily populate that test database with data?**

The example above should give you some pointers. I've found the best way to avoid conflicts between packages is to use unmanaged collections in tests (name = `null`). The `resetCollection` function should correctly avoid redefining any managed collections which are exported by other packages. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724530/can-you-use-tinytest-to-test-a-package-that-uses-other-packages) for more details.

Comment: This looks great. That's also awesome about the automatic separate database. I hadn't seen anything about that in the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work client side however. I get an error saying I can only remove by id.